# how to create an np array from a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a piece of code that indexes words using text blob. My current output comes from a for loop per 'doc' (like doc1, doc2, doc3, etc.)

From every doc I would like to have a vector of the 4 most important words and I wish to return its index number into a 4,1 np.array. I don't seem to be able to fix this unfortunately.

```
bloblist = [doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5, doc6, doc7, doc8, doc9, doc10, doc11]
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Top words in doc {}".format(i + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    corpus = blob.words
    wordIndex = list(enumerate(corpus))
    for word, score in sorted_words[:4]:
        arr = (corpus.index(word))
        print(arr)
```

this produces the following:

```
Top words in doc 1
5
0
1
2
Top words in doc 2
19
12
41
4
```

Which is cool but I would like to have it like this

```
Top words in doc 1
[5,0,1,2]
```

Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: First off, consider using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  Secondly, "I would like to have a vector of the 4 most important words and I wish to return its index number."  What index number?  The first occurrence?

Comment: You are printing arr at each iteration. I think what you are looking for is to initialise an array named arr before the second for loop, then append to this array each iteration, finally printing after the loop completes.

Comment: Hi Brad, yes, sorry, that index part wasn't really helpful. I indexed every single word using textblob so that you can have a fixed number for every document containing words for every word. Hmm, I find this hard to explain but basically I need a corpus based on many documents and then should be able to use the index of that to vectorise the top 4 words of every doc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Oli I've found the solution that works for me.

```
bloblist = [doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5, doc6, doc7, doc8, doc9, doc10, doc11]
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Top words in doc {}".format(i + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    corpus = blob.words
    wordIndex = list(enumerate(corpus))
    arr = np.array([])
    for word, score in sorted_words[:4]:
        arrw = np.array([corpus.index(word)])
        arr = np.concatenate((arr, arrw))
    print(arr)
    arr = arr.reshape(4,1)
    print(arr.shape)
```

that gives the following desired output:

```
Top words in doc 1
[ 5.  0.  1.  2.]
(4, 1)
Top words in doc 2
[ 19.  12.  41.   4.]
(4, 1)
Top words in doc 3
[ 16.   2.   6.   7.]
(4, 1)
```